# How to give user root access without giving him root password

Tags: security, permissions, root, accounts

The scenario is this:

- I have a development machine I want (need) to have root access to
- Our admin setups the machines using his own credentials for the root user. The explanation being that if something goes wrong or he needs to change something he just have to remember one password
- He then proceeds to give each user access to "sudo" without questioning for the password

Now I really dislike the fact that sudo wouldn't prompt me for my password. How does a user configuration look like that gives me and the admin complete root permissions (2 logins), with sudo prompting me for my password (and not root) look like?

Comment: Yeah. It is a little confusing. I don't often have to use sudo and having a password needed for it acts as a good safeguard for not ruining stuff. I can't use the password from root as its the sysadmins default password. He won't give the password to me, but he is ok with me running every command with sudo.

Comment: Which distro are you using?

Comment: I'm running OpenSuse 11.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type `visudo`, you will see something like this:

```
<your_user>  ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD:ALL
```

If you want `sudo` prompt for a password, just remove `NOPASSWD`

```
<your_user>  ALL=(ALL)   ALL
```

---

**UPDATE**

As @MikeyB mentioned, by default, `sudo` will prompt for a password of the invoking user. But if you turn on the `targetpw` flag:

```
Defaults targetpw
```

`sudo` will ask for the password of the target user.

Comment: But then it will prompt me for root's password which I don't have. I want it to prompt for mine

Comment: No - it will prompt you for your password. Sudo does not use the root password at all, only su does that.

Comment: No, you are wrong. It will prompt you for your password, not `root`.

Comment: I got to admit that I'm not that familiar with unix security model but this is what the terminal says after I changed `<your_user>  ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD:ALL` to `<your_user>  ALL=(ALL)   ALL`: `touch file`, `sudo rm file` `$ root's password:` and when I type in my own it states `Sorry, try again`

Comment: Ah, in your particular file the `targetpw` option is turned on.

Comment: What happens to the other users on the system if I turn off the option? Any side effects I don't see now?

Comment: It will prompt for their own password.

Comment: @quanta If you edit your answer to include the targetpw option, I'll accept it.

Comment: Frankly speaking, I forgot this option.

Comment: No problem. I'm new here. So what is the etiquette? Accept the answer if a comment points out missing some minor part of the solution?

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in the [sudoers(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) file, which you edit using visudo(8).

As the exmaples there show you, your current sudoers setup will look like this:

`%wheel         ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

You can change this to:

`%wheel         ALL = (ALL) ALL`

Answer (score 1):

This is just a remark...
Some people new with sudo may do the following mistake :
sudo -u root -i or sudo -s or sudo -i   -->which has the effect to ask your own password, and then if you re successful give you a brand new shell environment(/bin/bash) running with root privilege...
Wonderfull... yeah, BUT then the "sudo-newbie" wants to create a file...and he type the following : 
sudo touch myEpicStoriesWithSudo.txt

--> Of course now sudo will ask for a password... but not your own!!! the one of root because you were not you --> you were root

And you can replace root by any generic-user you want, I had the issue with a lot of DBA when we went to sudo "sudo -u oracle -i" ;)

I hope this can helps you with sudo and all the schizophrenic issue that come with it ;)
Regards